# It is possible to make an auto typing correction chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a chrome extension to correct user's typing on every website. I've searched around but found no solution. My idea is user highlighting a text and right click to correct it (I can't do it real time because the extension connect to a server running an Machine Learning model which will process the text).
Is there any idea or code can figure this out?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far otherwise nobody can help you. If you are new to chrome extensions read Getting Started tutorials. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Comment: It sounds like you want to build something like Grammarly? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/grammarly-for-chrome/kbfnbcaeplbcioakkpcpgfkobkghlhen?hl=en